# How can I change font weight in my project which has a default fontFamily for all textviews?

Tags: android, fonts, font-family, text-styling

I have a project and in this project I have defined fontFamily to all textviews in the style of AppTheme.

The fontFamily is `montserrat` but in text views I use `montserrat_semibold`, `montserrat_regular` and `montserrat_medium`.

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MontserratTextViewStyle</item>

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MontserratTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/montserrat</item>
    </style>
```

How can I change their weight in the different XMLs of textviews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm the only way I can think of doing that is to create multiple styles in your `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="MontserratTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/montserrat</item>
</style>

<style name="MontserratTextViewSemiBoldStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/montserrat_semibold</item>
</style>

<style name="MontserratTextViewRegularStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/montserrat_regualr</item>
</style>

<style name="MontserratTextViewMediumStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/montserrat_medium</item>
</style>
```

Then for any `TextView` which doesn't use the default `montserrat` i.e. maybe you want `montserrat_medium`:

```
<TextView
    style="@style/MontserratTextViewMediumStyle"
   ....
/>
```

Comment: Glad to be of help!